# Working with dynamic sub-domains with struts2

Tags: struts2

How do I create a sub-domain on my application server/container using Struts2.

For example, if I have a user called john15 I would like to dynamically create the sub-domain: `john15.abc.com`, after the user has signed in to my application at `abc.com`.

Comment: Sorry, john15 questions are *too broad* on SO

Comment: Going by intention rewrote the question, it should now be useful.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can't. There are ways to achieve this but sub-domains are controlled by the application server and so any programmatic control over them are limited by what the container/application server offers and would probably not be portable.

Another solution (which acheives the desired effect but without trying to use struts2/application server interaction) is to use struts2 to develop a custom url tag which builds your desired urls. Then using something that re-writes urls (software such as squid, and like: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Web_proxy_servers). You can rewrite the URL into a format which is more acceptable to struts, possibly as a url parameter, or make it appear as part of the path which can then be parsed.

If you must do this I would advise the proxy server solution. Implement urls to reach your actions following the template:

```
abc.com/user/additional_path_and_parameters
```

then use the web proxy to rewrite `user.abc.com/additional_path_and_parameters` into the above.

Finally in creating that magical stuts2 url tag and possibly a reimplementation of the action tag too: You'll probably want to reuse the existing tag(s) and have it implement urls for "production" and "development" modes. In development the tag would behave exactly as the existing struts2 url tag does, but during deployment mode it will write your urls as you need them. This is important because you don't want to waste time setting up a proxy on your development machines, that would be a pain.

Comment: Let me clarify the context of my question . I am trying to build a site like shopify - a do it yourself ecommerce website builder . Merchants provide content to let the system create there custom ecommerce web site hosted as a subdomain under my website . These site need to be  indexable by search engines . For example lets say a merchant has created a site named tulip on my website . So when any user types in tulip.mysite.com he will be shown the appropriate ecommerce website. By the way mysite.com is the name of my website. I was also thinking of using URL query  parameters as an alternative

Comment: The provided solution works just fine. The tools that do the indexing can only see what you've presented. A url remapping proxy server sits between the request and the application server. Your public nor your application server ever needs to be aware of the difference. The only trick is that struts2 provides tools to construct and display urls for you, these are the only points that should need to be aware of such a difference. I have rewritten urls but not for a java web application...

Comment: What I'm saying is don't make it an application issue (struts2) make it mainly a deployment configuration issue.